# Having trouble with add-content/general PS formatting

Tags: powershell

So ....  I'm trying to do the following and it isn't working, and I'm sure it's syntax (I'm very new to PS, so excuse my noob-ness).   Any advice?  I'm basically writing a running log file with fields delimited by a colon for who did what with my script.  Much thanks!!!

```
if(!(Test-Path C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt -PathType Leaf){New-Item C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt -ItemType File}

Add-Content "C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt (Get-Date -Format g):$env:USERNAME:Parameters Issued:$var1:$var2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
if(!(Test-Path "C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt" -PathType Leaf))
{New-Item "C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt" -ItemType File}

Add-Content "C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt" "$(Get-Date -Format g):$($env:USERNAME):Parameters Issued:$var1:$var2"
```

It must be run as admin to write on the root of the system drive.